# Do I really need to use mysql_real_escape_string when I save data in the DB?

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-real-escape-string, stripslashes

I am using `mysql_real_escape_string` to save content in my mySQL database. The content I save is HTML through a form. I delete and re-upload the PHP file that writes in DB when I need it.

To display correctly my HTML input I use `stripslashes()`

In other case, when I insert it without `mysql_real_escape_string`, I do not use `stripslashes()` on the output.

What is your opinion? Does `stripslashes` affect performance badly ?

Comment: In a sane world, you'd use parameterized SQL.

Comment: @Justin: unfortunately, it's an insane world, and that's inescapable...

Comment: @Mike: I see what you did there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do **not** use `stripslashes()`. It is utterly useless in terms of security, and there's no added benefit. This practice came from the dark ages of "magic quotes", a thing of the past that has been eliminated in the next PHP version.

Instead, only filter input:

- string: `mysql_real_escape_string($data)`
- integers: `(int)$data`
- floats: `(float)$data`
- boolean: `isset($data) && $data`

The output is a different matter. If you are storing HTML, you need to filter HTML against javascript.

**Edit:** If you have to do `stripslashes()` for the output to look correctly, than most probably you have magic quotes turned on. Some CMS even made the grave mistake to do their own magic quotes (eg: Wordpress). Always filter as I advised above, turn off magic quotes, and you should be fine.

Comment: The description field has `<img width=\"470\" height=\"270\" alt=\"/29/76/1302120047629.jpg\" src=\"https://domain.com/29/76/1302120047629.jpg\" title=\"/29/76/1302120047629.jpg\">` What is the code that will show this on a page instead of stripslashes ?

Comment: @Nikolai - As I said, you have to use `stripslashes()` in your case but only because **magic quotes is turned on**. This setting is useless, in fact it is being removed. If you turn it off and re-enter the content, you won't need to use `stripslashes()`.

Comment: I am on a shared server, I guess that will lead me in endless tickets. So, I guess I have to use `mysql_real_escape_string` for strings and `stripslashes`.

Answer (score 1):

Do not think about performance, **think about security**. Use `mysql_real_escape_string` everytime you're inserting data into DB

Answer (score 1):

No, don't escape it. Use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) instead. Store your data in its raw format, and process it as necessary for display - for example, use a suitable method to prevent Javascript from executing when displaying user supplied HTML.

See Bill Karwin's *Sql Injection Myths and Fallacies* [talk](http://www.ustream.tv/recorded/10772454) and [slides](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/sql-injection-myths-and-fallacies) for more information on this subject.

See [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/) and [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) for a couple of approaches to filter your HTML for output.

Comment: Ok, that's nice, but does anyone notice that I delete the form and re-upload it for those 3 minutes I need it ?

Comment: @Nikolai: I don't understand what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

It is always best to scrub your data for potential malicious or overlooked special characters which might throw errors or corrupt your database.

Per PHP docs, it even says "If this function is not used to escape data, the query is vulnerable to [SQL Injection Attacks](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php)."

Comment: **Don't. even. mention. stripslashes/addslashes.**

Comment: I'm just paranoid on the practice, that's all. Sorry for the scare :-P

Answer (score 0):

Check out a database abstraction library that does all this and more for you automatically, such as ADOdb at http://adodb.sourceforge.net/

It addresses a lot of the concerns others have brought up such as security / parameterization. I doubt any performance saved is worth the developer hassle to do all this manually every query, or the security practices sacrificed.